# Bittorrent UDP implementation

Tags: udp, bittorrent

Can someone point me to some documentation on how to implement a Bittorrent UDP application?
I am working on a Bittorrent application and I can successfully download using TCP but I want to implement UDP and I can't find any information on it.  I am retrieving peers with UDP trackers but that approach appears different than downloading files.
If I sniff a UDP Handshake I see the following in Wireshark:

172.16.49.213  5.31.44.30   UDP 62  35507 → 18318 Len=20

5.31.44.30 172.16.49.213   UDP 62  18318 → 35507 Len=20

This is done before the handshake.  Also, it looks like there are 20 bytes prepended to the Handshake (different than the 20 bytes above).

So I need some information to help me with what all this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BitTorrent Peer Wire Protocol over UDP, called **uTP** is specified in:
[BEP29 - uTorrent transport protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20161228180615/http://www.bittorrent.org:80/beps/bep_0029.html)

BitTorrentInc has also published uTP as a IETF RFC were they call it LEDBAT:
[RFC 6817 - Low Extra Delay Background Transport (LEDBAT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6817)

However, I wouldn't recommend anyone to do their own implementation, (except as a learning experience), as it involves a lot of time critical, low level network IO and is very tricky to get right.

Instead I recommend to use the library: https://github.com/bittorrent/libutp
Almost all clients implementing uTP uses this library. AFAIK, the only exception is [libtorrent/rasterbar](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent) (used by qBittorrent and Deluge) and it don't work as good as [libutp](https://github.com/bittorrent/libutp) does.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean as to creating my own implementation but I will give it a try.  Honestly I saw BEP29 in my research but I guess it didn't register that it was what I was looking for.

Comment: If BEP29 is the only documentation on UDP I can see why others have not implemented it. I've searched but I can't find any other information on utp.