# UDP communication in BitTorrent

Tags: udp, ip, bittorrent

So I am seeding on BitTorrent and there appears to be two-fold communication showing up on Wireshark. From peers around the world I receive UDP packets with 20 bytes of data. In response my BitTorrent sends UDP packets with around 1438 bytes of data.

This [uTorrent protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20161228180615/http://www.bittorrent.org:80/beps/bep_0029.html) suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260463/bittorrent-udp-implementation) does not seem to have anything as small as the 28 byte (20 bytes data 8 bytes header) UDP packets, likewise [this link](http://xbtt.sourceforge.net/udp_tracker_protocol.html) isn't helpful.

What is the formal communication mechanism or protocol at play here? Is it possible to analyze those 1438-byte packets or in more detail in order to get a snippet of the file being sent? Or the structure of the 20 bytes of data being sent from my peers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> This uTorrent protocol suggested here does not seem to have anything as small as the 28 byte (20 bytes data 8 bytes header) UDP packets

The µTP header is 20 bytes. So those most likely are ACK messages. Wireshark should support decoding those packets, at least if you captured a connection from the beginning.